# Azure Upgrading MySQL Database (ClearDB) Version from v5.5 to v5.7

Tags: mysql, azure, cloud, cleardb

I'm using `Django` to create an API with `MySQL` as the database. I'm using `JSONField` in my code and my local MySQL version is v5.7 so JSON field is supported. But **Azure's** MySQL version is **v5.5** and JSON field is not supported.

Is there a way to upgrade MySQL on Azure?

Comment: What do you mean, when you say 'Azure's MySQL version'? If you're referring to ClearDB's hosted MySQL (since you tagged as such), then I'd think you'd need to reach out to them. If you're working with VM images, you can install whatever version you want to.

Comment: You are right, I just checked with their website and some forums, it seems that they haven't upgraded in a long time. And from what I understood they don't plan to do it because `MySQL v5.6` has backward compatibility problems. I guess I'll try out installing a custom VM. Thank you.